# Automatic Insert to Another Table

Tags: php, mysql

i'm working on a certain system that evaluates the performance of teachers.

Table 1:

```
Student (student_id,student_name,teachers,subjects)
```

Table 2:

```
Teacher (teacher id, teacher_name, subjects)
```

Is it possible that i can automatically insert some of data in the columns of Table 2 while inserting to the Table 1, by just one script? And can reference such that everytime a student login, he already knows who will he/she evaluates based on the subjects enrolled of the student and the teacher teaches. Did I make sense? Hoping for your response! Thanks Guys!

Comment: `MySQL Trigger can be a way around to this`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref AFTER INSERT ON Student
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Teacher
   ( 
     teacher_name,
     deleted_by)
   VALUES
   ( 
     NEW.subject,
     NEW.teacher_name );

  END;
```

Comment: Thanks dude! much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1)

> can automatically insert some of data in the columns of Table 2 while inserting to the Table 1, by just one script?

You need to look at adding [database triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) for that. But just from experience, I can tell you that the team I work with will never use database triggers. It tends to complicate your system and makes it difficult to maintain and find bugs. Try first to implement a method in your program that always inserts both rows in a single transaction. Then whenever you need to perform those insertions, just call that method.

Problem 2)

> And can reference such that everytime a student login, he already knows who will he/she evaluates based on the subjects enrolled of the student and the teacher teaches.

Um, you may have to place that in a separate post and provide a lot more details.

Comment: Ok sir. The Problem 2 sir? How can I correctly approach this? Any idea I can start with? Thanks sir!